IRAF mask images with sigma clipping
I have a school homework which MUST use IRAF
First I have to produce a median background from this image

but before fmedian image x y I need to mask out all the stars
I am going to do this from a sigma clipping, for example mask out all pixels with sigma>3
How to mask images with sigma clipping in IRAF?

It's not stackexchange, but there is an iraf forum https://iraf.net/forum/  -- might want to tone down the language if you ask there!
